# Nginx, ffmpeg HTTPS to RTMP

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I have a web server that's root page is a continuous changing image from a camera.  This I can view across the web in a browser without issue.

What I really want to do however is a Nginx with the RTMP extension to take the HTTP and convert to a RTMP stream.  Which I think is something like this...

```
worker_processes auto;
rtmp_auto_push on;
events {}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        listen [::]:1935 ipv6only=on;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
            exec_pull /usr/bin/ffmpeg -f image2 - loop -i https://<domain> -f flv rtmp://localhost/show/stream;
        }
    }
}
```

However that doesn't work, it doesn't do anything, no error, no result.  If I point VLC at the expected stream I get not a sausage.

If anyone has any ideas on what is wrong I would be very grateful.

Tom